# React-Jest Unit test an external module method that affects state

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am working on a React application using Jest.

I want to test an imported module component method (closemodal):

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.showModal}
  closemodal={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })} // <= this one
  type="slideInDown"
>
```

I tried in my unit test to spy Modal closemodal method like that:

```
import Modal from "react-animated-modal";

let spyOnCloseModal;

beforeEach(() => {
  spyOnCloseModal = jest.spyOn(Modal, "closemodal");
  wrapper = shallow(<App />);
});
```

But when UT running I get this error: 
`Cannot spy the closemodal property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a mock function.

```
test("checks closemodel", () => {
  const props = {
    closemodal: jest.fn()
  };
  const wrapper = shallow(<Modal {...props} />);

  // trigger your `closemodal` function here

  expect(props.closemodal).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```